# How to share and cache DLLs for a Multi-tenant application

Tags: c#, caching, azure-service-fabric

I have an application that does the following :

1. Creates an AppDomain for executing a process when an API receives a processing request.
2. Loads a set of dlls required for executing some tasks on a Service Fabric application.
3. Executes the whole process in that app domain.
4. Unloads the AppDomain and returns the response.

Now there are some scenarios,

- In most of the cases, DLLS are same for users. For instance, when the application is doing some default work for each tenant, the DLLs would be specific to that work, but there is also a provision to add custom work for each tenant which they can use themselves.
- There are multiple versions of same dll used by different tenants.

Now for this application, as we are continuously loading and unloading dlls through appdomain container, The APIs are performing really slow. Also, even though the application works perfectly, the resources used are not optimized. (We are paying more on memory and compute without getting performance).

So I need some option to optimize this.

1. Can we use Dll Caching somehow similar to data caching, such that the same 
   dll is loaded only once, but when request comes from multiple users, we can 
   create an instance of the class and call the resource?
2. When a new custom dll is loaded, the same will be loaded for that particular 
   tenant not affecting others.

Please suggest what are the best options one can have in these scenarios.

Comment: Do you use AppDomains for versioning? If so, why not just deploy multiple service versions inside multiple applications?

Comment: I was actually trying to minimise cost such that we can share cost between tenants.

Comment: Why do you use custom AppDomains in the first place? You could create an App Service per tenant and deploy the same code to app service. Some dlls will be loaded, some others won't depending on the tenant.

Comment: But as I mentioned, some Dlls might need caching too. For instance if one dll is just doing some regular common stuffs, loading it to all the tenant will be unnecessary.  I am thinking on optimising the environment such that I could save some money out of unused memory in cloud. Think in case of separate app service per tenant, I need to bear same memory for an user who is not using the dll for long time, if I make it long running. 

The AppDomains are killing it and taking even longer time to do operation, so I would want to remove it asap.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your problem. Is memory really an issue? Are you using like thousands of Dlls, like one per each user action? Your design seems complicated, no offense. Anyhow, you're speaking about memory usage, not "performance and scape up" as in the bounty def. Both targets may be kinda orthogonal.

Comment: No no, memory isnt an issue, it is how fast the process executes. For instance, I can share the same data which is common for every user in a cache server, In the same manner, I wanted to optimize the process execution, such that the tenant using common dlls will reuse the existing loaded dlls while others will load/unload dlls. Making a service for every execution somewhat works, but depending on payload, I need to elastically increase/decrease the consumption of resources. Also loading/unloading time is one of the concern.

Comment: I must agree with @SimonMourier, your design looks a bit over engineered and there are many ways to handle this , however your question is too broad and is not clear how much you are willing to change your design or how a generic answer will help you. My general recommendation is remove the AppDomain approach you have and check Lazy Loading, maybe you can use this for the per-tenant dlls, as the app will only load to memory what you really need by your execution flow, anyways this do not fix "AppDomain setup time" with the common dlls.

Comment: @JesusSalas I was thinking to make change the architecture like this, do you think this is good approach?  

1. Create a new service which loads all the dependent DLLS and will call the common methods from the service. (which will ensure shared dlls are loaded once).
2. For each process request, if there is a requirement to load additional Customer specific dlls, I would use Reflection to load it to memory and unload them after use. 
3. The application will serialize the data to call specific method and it will work similar to Request - Response model (SOA).

Comment: Looks like a good option, however, why to unload them? If memory is not a problem you should keep them in memory, the loading/unloading time is what is killing you, you can use a DI Container to engage with the dependencies you need, for instance, by using ninject look to the "name bindings" section here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding you can use the unique identifier of your tenant to load the dlls that are specific for each one.